# BigQuery: cast string as datetime

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a column with millions of dates called 'timestamp' in bigquery, but they are marked as string.

The format of the timestamp column is as follows:

```
2022-02-09T12:01:51.911821Z
```

for every observation in the dataset.

I wish to convert it to datetime and have tried the following:

```
SELECT
  CAST(timestamp AS DATETIME)
FROM
  `bigquery_table`
LIMIT
  1000
```

The query will process but I am told that 'Invalid datetime string "2022-02-09T12:01:51.911821Z"'. Any suggestions to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That might be ISO 8601 format, you can use [`PARSE_TIMESTAMP`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#datetime-functions) function.

```
SELECT
  PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E*SZ', timestamp)
FROM
  `bigquery_table`
LIMIT
  1000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to first cast it as datetimeoffset as per:
`select cast(cast('2022-02-09T12:01:51.911821Z' as datetimeoffset) as datetime)`

Comment: Hmm doesnt seem like BigQuery finds datetimeoffset command